# Pinned subview of a popover controller having a tableview inside

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to add a hovering subview to a UIPopoverController. I have a table view controller as a content view controller inside the popover. I tried to add it as a normal subview:

```
UIPopoverController* popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myTableViewController];
UIView* mySubview = ...
[popoverController.contentViewController.view addSubview:mySubView];
```

It is displayed correctly but unfortunately scrolls up and down with the table view. I would like to have its position fixed.

I also tried to update the position of the subview by the y offset of the scrollview in the scrollViewDidScroll: method of the table view controller, but would like to avoid this solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the content controller a UIViewController subclass rather than a UITableViewController subclass.